# Make sure that the tweets I got in each request are different in twitter API?

Tags: python, api, twitter, sandbox

I am using twitter API (premium sandbox) in python and the maximum tweets I can get on one request is 100, so if I need 500 tweets on one day that means I need to do request 5 times but how can I make sure that the tweets I got in each request are different not duplicate?

and also, Is it possible to get the number of tweets in a specific hashtag based on days? , any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc for Premium Search: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search.html

See the `next` parameter. Basically, along with the 100 results you should see a "next" property. In your next search request include the `next` parameter with the value returned in "next".

With Premium Sandbox you cannot get counts for specific days.

Comment: is there any example in python, I use gen_rule_payload function

Comment: I use [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI). It has python code that does what you need in [this library function](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/TwitterAPI/TwitterPager.py). Or, you can modify [this simple example](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py) to call the Premium Search.